# Android CheckBox in ListView get focus

Tags: android, list, listview, checkbox, focus

I have a ListView, each item has a TextView and a CheckBox. I want that the user can select each item by pressing the row. But the checkbox also gets focus. I want to remove the focus from the checkbox when a list item is clicked.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@android:id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshots when the list item is pressed:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

additionally disable focusableInTouchMode:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

or

```
myCheckBox.setFocusable(false);
myCheckBox.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

or catch it at the top of the row's onClickListener:

```
myCheckBox.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the getView() method,

```
holder.multiselect_checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    //do something suitable for you
                }
            });
```

here

> holder.multiselect_checkbox

is your checkbox object name.

This will remove the focus of your checkbox.